# The text on moderator tags in posts is blue when I've visited the tag page

Tags: bug, tags, design, meta, moderator-tags

When I've visited a tag page for a moderator tag (`https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/*`), the text on a moderator tag is blue when it is used in posts. For example, the following screenshot is from the end of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/349538), when I've visited the page for the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag:

> [image]

I also looked at how this is displayed Meta Stack Overflow and there it's black instead of blue (I guess that has to do with the theme on child Metas is black and the theme on Meta Stack Exchange is blue):

> [image]

Also, in the preview, either when editing a post or asking a question, the tag renders normally.

Besides, in Firefox, the font color turns red for a very short time when the cursor enters or leaves the tag:

> [image]

However, this only happens in Firefox. In Chrome, Edge and Internet Explorer, the font color is just blue and never changes.

Can this bug please be fixed?

Comment: They're styled `a` elements on the page - so once they're visited they get the appropriate styling for a visited link. While in a `form` (editing a post etc...) they're not `a` elements on the page so won't render as visited even if you have done so... So I'd say that's by design - unless you're referring to the fact that the UI should maybe override or change the visited decoration to not highlight it?

Comment: @JonClements You're right, I just tested it on [status-completed]. I think that it should be fixed so that it's always red no matter if I visited the link or not. I think it looks better with red than with blue.

Comment: You should edit your question to reflect that

Comment: @AnthonyPham Done

Comment: Also the font color is blinking when mouse pointer is covering/leaving the tag. You could use [this gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCvk9.gif) in your post if you would.

Comment: @alexolut It only does that in Firefox. I tested in Firefox, Chrome and Edge and in Firefox it does as you described and in Chrome and Edge it only does as I described in my question (my screenshots are from Chrome). Anyway, I will edit to add it to my question.

Comment: [It's worse on Graphic Design Meta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcPn4m.png)

Comment: @Cai status-by-graphic-design :)